# Adding Nodes / Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Im trying to add some nodes in my existing cluster. Can I choose th amount of the hard drive space? Or can I only give the new nodes not more space than I gave to the existing nodes? (my nodes have each 12TB)

Answer (score 1):

> Can I choose th amount of the hard drive space?

You can't "choose space", but you can chose which directories are used for the data nodes, which in sum, add to the total availability space, yes.

Not all datanodes need to be the same size

Comment: does that mean that my new nodes must not have more than 12 TB of hard drive space?

Comment: That's not what I said... They can have as much as you want, they don't need to be all the same size, is all. For example, we have datanodes that range between 32 - 52 TB