# adding nodes in an existing cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I would like to increase my cluster. I have 20 slave nodes, dual-quad-core CPUs, each hard drive space is 12 TB. I would like to add 10 additional slave nodes. Do I have to care about the disk space on my new nodes? Can my nodes have any amount of hard drive space?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Nodes / Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51769119/adding-nodes-hadoop)

Comment: Please don't repost questions

Comment: Im sorry, it was not on purpose, I was disordering. Hadoop is such a big Chapter.